# Convert enum to Dictionary<int,string> but string is the description attribute

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I try to convert an enum to Dictionary int is the value and string is the description of the value.

I already have a function that gets the enum description by it's value but I don't how to use it with the enum iteration I have:

```
public static IDictionary<int, string> ConvertEnumToDictionary<K>()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> mydic = new Dictionary<int, string>(); 
            foreach (K foo in Enum.GetValues(typeof(K)))
            {
                //???
                mydic.Add((int)foo, GetEnumDescription(foo));
            } 
        }

public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        // Get the Description attribute value for the enum value
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }

  public enum Lu_LanguageTypes
        {
            [Description("Hebrew")]
            he = 1,
            [Description("Englishj")]
            en = 2,
            [Description("Spanish")]
            es = 3
        }
```

Comment: Can you share `Enum` example? `where K : Enum` may help you, if you are using C# 7.3. Also, why `GetEnumDescription` isn't a generic method?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I added

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I had to upgrade to c# 7.3, thanks , how can I change GetEnumDescription to generic?

Comment: `GetEnumDescription` isn't required to be a generic in this case, since it accepts `Enum` argument already and `K` constrained to `Enum` in `ConvertEnumToDictionary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `ConvertEnumToDictionary` method a little bit and apply [`where K : Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints) generic constraint (available from C# 7.3) and cast `Enum` value to `K` before passing to `GetEnumDescription` method

```cs
public static IDictionary<int, string> ConvertEnumToDictionary<K>() where K : Enum
{
    var mydic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    foreach (var foo in Enum.GetValues(typeof(K)))
    {
        mydic.Add((int)foo, GetEnumDescription((K)foo));
    }

    return mydic;
}
```

Example of the usage, which gives a dictionary with 3 key-value pairs

```cs
var result = ConvertEnumToDictionary<Lu_LanguageTypes>();
```

Another option is to add constraint to `IConvertible` interface as well (since `Enum` type implements it) and avoid casting

```cs
public static IDictionary<int, string> ConvertEnumToDictionary<K>() where K : Enum, IConvertible
{
    var mydic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    foreach (K foo in Enum.GetValues(typeof(K)))
    {
        mydic.Add(foo.ToInt32(null), GetEnumDescription(foo));
    }

    return mydic;
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you.
Why it isn't generic, why should it be?

Comment: @OffirPe'er Glad, that it helps. Sorry, didn't get your point regarding generic. The point here is use `where K : Enum` constraint, `ConvertEnumToDictionary` is generic already. `GetEnumDescription` isn't needed to be generic, since is accepts `Enum` argument already, I've missed that initilally